# How to insert a SQL query from a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, sqlplus

I have made a batch file which connects to sqlplus and starts two different windows. I made 2 windows. 1 for table viewing and 1 for the actual operation. By doing this I have simplified my task by 50%. But I still need to insert queries in 1 window to check relational data. How would I automate this?

I found this:

```
@echo on
start cmd /K sqlplus dipak/dipak
start cmd /K sqlplus dipak/dipak
```

In the above code, `dipak` is my username and `dipak` is the password, *(educaional user)*.

I want to insert sql query in first sqlplus command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those insert statements are stored into a .sql file (let's call it `dipak.sql`), then you'd call it as

```
@echo on
start cmd /K sqlplus dipak/dipak @dipak.sql           --> this
start cmd /K sqlplus dipak/dipak
```

Comment: is it possible to pass a query insted of  "@dipak.sql" in your mentioned solution. Your solution is working 100 % but   i  am curious about that.

Comment: That's not possible, as far as I can tell. Try to put this line into the BAT script: `start cmd /k sqlplus dipak/dipak select * from dept;` and run it. Nothing will happen; SQLPLUS will display **help** information which shows valid options; there's nothing like "executing a query" directly - you have to call a script.